# PrimeFaces Ajax Listener not executed when process attribute is specified for a different component

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

When I specify `process` attribute of `p:ajax` tag, the listener is not executed. If I omit the `process` attribute, then the listener is called as expected.

Here is the view snippet:

```
<p:messages id="messages" />
<h:inputText id="inputToProcess" value="#{controller.inputToProcess}" />
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="testCheckbox" >
  <p:ajax event="change" process="inputToProcess"
    update="messages @this inputToUpdate"
    listener="#{controller.processChecked}" />
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
<h:inputText id="inputToUpdate" value="#{controller.inputToUpdate}" />
```

And Controller:

```
@javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean
@javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped
public class Controller implements Serializable {
  private String inputToProcess;
  private String inputToUpdate;
  //getters and setters

  public void processChecked(javax.faces.AjaxBehaviorEvent e) {
    // doing some stuff here
  }
}
```

I attached a `phaseListener` to a view with `ANY_PHASE` *PhaseId*, and here is what I observed.

When I specify `process` attribute , the value of the *inputToProcess* input is successfully set to the controller during the Update Model phase (no exception occurs). Then the `Invoke Application` and `Render Response` phases are executed, but no listener is called. One thing  I noticed is that checkbox is not set in the end. But, there are no conversion or validation errors, because as I said the `Update Model` and `Invoke Application` phases are executed.

If I omit `process` attribute, here is what I see: the listener is normally called during the `Invoke Application` phase (since `immediate` is false by default), and then `Render Response is executed. Checkbox is successfully set.

Is there any explanation for this sort of behavior?

Comment: What if you add `@this` to `process`? What if you use standard JSF checkbox and ajax components instead of PrimeFaces ones?

Comment: @BalusC I'm tired counting how many times you have helped me. Thanks a ton! Adding `@this` to `process` worked for me. Are you able to explain why? I thought that the `listener` should be triggered no matter, whether `@this` is specified in `process` or not. Might this be an issue? The problem with the standard JSF checkbox and ajax components, is that the listener is invoked during `Process Validations` phase, but I need to update the model first! Anywho, post this as an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: An issue was added at: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/509, but they don't want to fix it unfortunately. Please go in and comment and vote on it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It should work fine at first sight. At least, it works fine that way when using standard JSF components. I'd bet it to be a bug or "feature" of PrimeFaces that it doesn't process the action when the action component is not included in the `process`. Adding `@this` to `process` should solve it. Consider posting an issue report to PrimeFaces guys.

Further, I'd rather use `event="valueChange"` or `event="click"` instead of `event="change"` or just remove the `event` altogether, it defaults to the right value already (`valueChange` which will render `onclick` in checkbox and radio button components). The `change` event works differently in MSIE for checkboxes and radiobuttons. It's only triggered on 2nd click and forth. You don't want to be browser dependent.

---

As per your comment:

> *The problem with the standard JSF checkbox and ajax components, is that the listener is invoked during Process Validations phase, but I need to update the model first!*

This is not true. Probably you was using `valueChangeListener` instead of `<f:ajax listener>` or confusing the one with the other. The `<f:ajax listener>` is always invoked during invoke action phase.

Comment: Excellent! You were right, I used `valueChangeListener`. One last question. With `f:ajax`, what event should I specify? Or does it default to the right value as well as with `p:ajax`?

Comment: Yes, it does. The default is always `event="valueChange"` for `UIInput` components and `event="action"` for `UICommand` components. On `UIInput` components it will translate to `change` for HTML input/select/textarea elements and to `click` for HTML radio/checkbox elements.

Comment: Though `process` defaults to `@this` as described in the Primefaces documentation, `@this` is surprisingly not processed if you have other component ids in `process`.

Comment: @MattHandy I'm aware that it's not processed when I specify the component id, other than `@this`. But should it prevent triggering the listener? I don't think so. Because the ajax request is actually posted.